# Error while run application in tomcat

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, gwt, gxt

I have an application in maven(3.0.4)/GWT(2.6.1)/GXT(3.1.1). When I develop in Eclipse/Jetty, the application runs without problems!
When I create a war and I deploy in tomcat(7.0.55), in some Grid I have a problem!
I have not an error in server log but in firebug console I have this:

```
GMT+200 2015 com.google.gwt.logging.client.LogConfiguration
SEVERE: Exception caught: (TypeError) : Cannot set property 'disabled' of undefinedcom.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: Exception caught: (TypeError) : Cannot set property 'disabled' of undefined
    at Unknown.com_google_gwt_core_client_impl_StackTraceCreator$CollectorEmulated_$fillInStackTrace__Lcom_google_gwt_core_client_impl_StackTraceCreator$CollectorEmulated_2Ljava_lang_Throwable_2V(StackTraceCreator.java:180)
    at Unknown.java_lang_Throwable_fillInStackTrace__Ljava_lang_Throwable_2(StackTraceCreator.java:518)
    at Unknown.java_lang_RuntimeException_RuntimeException__Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_Throwable_2V(Throwable.java:62)
    at Unknown.com_google_web_bindery_event_shared_UmbrellaException_UmbrellaException__Ljava_util_Set_2V(UmbrellaException.java:71)
    at Unknown.com_google_gwt_event_shared_UmbrellaException_UmbrellaException__Ljava_util_Set_2V(UmbrellaException.java:26)
    at Unknown.com_google_gwt_event_shared_EventBus_$castFireEvent__Lcom_google_gwt_event_shared_EventBus_2Lcom_google_gwt_event_shared_GwtEvent_2V(UmbrellaException.java:90)
    at Unknown.com_keinavo_tutorials_shared_model_AppModel_$setDynamicModelEmpty__Lcom_keinavo_tutorials_shared_model_AppModel_2Lcom_keinavo_tutorials_shared_model_dynamic_DynamicModel_2ZV(AppModel.java:107)
    at Unknown.com_keinavo_tutorials_client_AppController$6_$onSuccess__Lcom_keinavo_tutorials_client_AppController$6_2Lcom_keinavo_tutorials_shared_model_dynamic_DynamicModel_2V(AppController.java:231)
    at Unknown.com_keinavo_tutorials_client_AppController$6_onSuccess__Ljava_lang_Object_2V(AppController.java:230)
    at Unknown.com_google_gwt_user_client_rpc_impl_RequestCallbackAdapter_$onResponseReceived__Lcom_google_gwt_user_client_rpc_impl_RequestCallbackAdapter_2Lcom_google_gwt_http_client_Request_2Lcom_google_gwt_http_client_Response_2V(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:232)
    at Unknown.com_google_gwt_http_client_Request_$fireOnResponseReceived__Lcom_google_gwt_http_client_Request_2Lcom_google_gwt_http_client_RequestCallback_2V(Request.java:259)
    at Unknown.com_google_gwt_http_client_RequestBuilder$1_onReadyStateChange__Lcom_google_gwt_xhr_client_XMLHttpRequest_2V(RequestBuilder.java:412)
    at Unknown.anonymous(XMLHttpRequest.java:351)
    at Unknown.com_google_gwt_core_client_impl_Impl_apply__Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2(Impl.java:299)
    at Unknown.com_google_gwt_core_client_impl_Impl_entry0__Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2(Impl.java:356)
    at Unknown.anonymous(Impl.java:94)
Caused by: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) : Cannot set property 'disabled' of undefined
    at Unknown.com_google_gwt_core_client_impl_StackTraceCreator$CollectorEmulated_$fillInStackTrace__Lcom_google_gwt_core_client_impl_StackTraceCreator$CollectorEmulated_2Ljava_lang_Throwable_2V(StackTraceCreator.java:180)
    at Unknown.java_lang_Throwable_fillInStackTrace__Ljava_lang_Throwable_2(StackTraceCreator.java:518)
    at Unknown.java_lang_Throwable_Throwable__V(Throwable.java:51)
    at Unknown.java_lang_Exception_Exception__V(Exception.java:25)
    at Unknown.java_lang_RuntimeException_RuntimeException__V(RuntimeException.java:25)
    at Unknown.com_google_gwt_core_client_JavaScriptException_JavaScriptException__Ljava_lang_Object_2V(JavaScriptException.java:117)
    at Unknown.com_google_gwt_lang_Exceptions_getCachableJavaScriptException__Ljava_lang_Object_2Lcom_google_gwt_core_client_JavaScriptException_2(Exceptions.java:45)
    at Unknown.com_google_gwt_lang_Exceptions_wrap__Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2(Exceptions.java:29)
    at Unknown.com_google_gwt_dom_client_Element_$setPropertyBoolean__Lcom_google_gwt_dom_client_Element_2Ljava_lang_String_2ZV(Element.java:733)
    at Unknown.com_keinavo_tutorials_client_grid_GridEditingDynamicModel_asWidget__Lcom_google_gwt_user_client_ui_Widget_2(GridEditingDynamicModel.java:67)
    at Unknown.com_sencha_gxt_widget_core_client_container_VerticalLayoutContainer_$add__Lcom_sencha_gxt_widget_core_client_container_VerticalLayoutContainer_2Lcom_google_gwt_user_client_ui_IsWidget_2Lcom_sencha_gxt_widget_core_client_container_VerticalLayoutContainer$VerticalLayoutData_2V(VerticalLayoutContainer.java:141)
    at Unknown.com_keinavo_tutorials_client_panel_data_DataPanel_$addGridEmpty__Lcom_keinavo_tutorials_client_panel_data_DataPanel_2Lcom_keinavo_tutorials_shared_model_dynamic_DynamicModel_2V(DataPanel.java:81)
    at Unknown.com_keinavo_tutorials_client_event_LoadDynamicModelEmptyEvent_$dispatch__Lcom_keinavo_tutorials_client_event_LoadDynamicModelEmptyEvent_2Lcom_keinavo_tutorials_client_event_LoadDynamicModelEmptyHandler_2V(LoadDynamicModelEmptyEvent.java:28)
    at Unknown.com_keinavo_tutorials_client_event_LoadDynamicModelEmptyEvent_dispatch__Lcom_google_gwt_event_shared_EventHandler_2V(LoadDynamicModelEmptyEvent.java:27)
    at Unknown.com_google_web_bindery_event_shared_SimpleEventBus_$doFire__Lcom_google_web_bindery_event_shared_SimpleEventBus_2Lcom_google_web_bindery_event_shared_Event_2Ljava_lang_Object_2V(SimpleEventBus.java:194)
    at Unknown.com_google_gwt_event_shared_EventBus_$castFireEvent__Lcom_google_gwt_event_shared_EventBus_2Lcom_google_gwt_event_shared_GwtEvent_2V(EventBus.java:67)
    at Unknown.com_keinavo_tutorials_shared_model_AppModel_$setDynamicModelEmpty__Lcom_keinavo_tutorials_shared_model_AppModel_2Lcom_keinavo_tutorials_shared_model_dynamic_DynamicModel_2ZV(AppModel.java:107)
    at Unknown.com_keinavo_tutorials_client_AppController$6_$onSuccess__Lcom_keinavo_tutorials_client_AppController$6_2Lcom_keinavo_tutorials_shared_model_dynamic_DynamicModel_2V(AppController.java:231)
    at Unknown.com_keinavo_tutorials_client_AppController$6_onSuccess__Ljava_lang_Object_2V(AppController.java:230)
    at Unknown.com_google_gwt_user_client_rpc_impl_RequestCallbackAdapter_$onResponseReceived__Lcom_google_gwt_user_client_rpc_impl_RequestCallbackAdapter_2Lcom_google_gwt_http_client_Request_2Lcom_google_gwt_http_client_Response_2V(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:232)
    at Unknown.com_google_gwt_http_client_Request_$fireOnResponseReceived__Lcom_google_gwt_http_client_Request_2Lcom_google_gwt_http_client_RequestCallback_2V(Request.java:259)
    at Unknown.com_google_gwt_http_client_RequestBuilder$1_onReadyStateChange__Lcom_google_gwt_xhr_client_XMLHttpRequest_2V(RequestBuilder.java:412)
    at Unknown.anonymous(XMLHttpRequest.java:351)
    at Unknown.com_google_gwt_core_client_impl_Impl_apply__Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2(Impl.java:299)
    at Unknown.com_google_gwt_core_client_impl_Impl_entry0__Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2(Impl.java:356)
    at Unknown.anonymous(Impl.java:94)
```

Thanks
Manolo

Comment: `SEVERE: Exception caught: (TypeError) : Cannot set property 'disabled' of undefinedcom.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: Exception caught: (TypeError) : Cannot set property 'disabled' of undefined

` Are you applying styles that are not supporting `disabled` where is your GWT code causing this ?

Comment: To go further, `of undefined` means that something is null, so you can't set its disabled property (yet).

Answer (score 1):

```
Caused by: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) : Cannot set property 'disabled' of undefined
    […]
    at Unknown.com_google_gwt_dom_client_Element_$setPropertyBoolean__Lcom_google_gwt_dom_client_Element_2Ljava_lang_String_2ZV(Element.java:733)
    at Unknown.com_keinavo_tutorials_client_grid_GridEditingDynamicModel_asWidget__Lcom_google_gwt_user_client_ui_Widget_2(GridEditingDynamicModel.java:67)
```

It looks like your `GridEditingDynamicModel#asWidget()` somehow returns `null` (actually, JS `undefined`, which could mean for example that you're returning a field value that has non been initialized).

Comment: I resolved!
In my class there was:
grid.getView().getScroller().enable();
The scroller was null!

Thanks!